# php Show title attribute on page load

Tags: php, title

Hi guys is there a way in php or javascript, that every time i load a page. the title attribute(comments) will always always show then disappear after 2-3 secsonds

example;

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Untitled</title>
    </head>

<body>

      <img src='images/test.jpg' title="This is what im saying"></img>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes.  Why you would want to do so is questionable.  This forum is not for asking if things are possible or having us do them for you, but when you have tried something and have a problem, how to continue past your problem.

Comment: well i actually dont know how to to that. thats why im asking. im new to web programming sorry for the noob question.

Comment: i have a random user and i want them to notice one specific link

Answer (score 0):

Use something like below..

```
   <html>
    <head>
      <title>Untitled</title>
    </head>

<body>

      <img src='images/test.jpg' id="imageID" title="This is what im saying"></img>
</body>

</html>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ $('#imageID').attr('title','');}, 3000);
})
</script>
```

Comment: OMFG! Include jquery only for timeout? You must try Vanilla JS framework! http://vanilla-js.com/

Comment: hi is there any configuration i need to do? cause i copied and pasted that code but nothing happen.

Comment: @deep im actually not using any framework :(, after this project i will start studying using php framework.

Comment: no other configuration required, You want remove <title>Untitled</title> after 2-3 sec. right?

Comment: no i want this 
      <img src='images/test.jpg' title="This is what im saying"></img> title attribute to show automatic when page is load. then hide after 3 secs